# Why does my Next.JS edit code work (on npm run start)? without new build (on npm run build)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Why does my Next.JS edit code work (on npm run start)? without new build (on npm run build). I wonder why it is so. Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the `scripts` in your `package.json`?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 5000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }

Comment: What's in `server.js`?

Comment: in the server.js i did createServer and set up for openssl.

Comment: Can you please show us that file's code?

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs .. if you want to run development server, you have to run

```
 npm run dev
```

npm run start --> Runs your production build.

Please check your scripts in package.json